# Transferring data from temporary table to main table using cursor plsql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables.
temp table has 12 columns
main table has 14 columns

Main table has incrementing id and the one more column have a default value
I need to put the values in the main table from temp table using cursors and looping
This is what I have so far

```
DECLARE
    type R_REQ is record ( v_branch accountrequest.branch%type,
                           v_account_type accountrequest.account_type%type,
                           v_title accountrequest.title%type,
                           v_firstname accountrequest.firstname%type,
                           v_lastname accountrequest.lastname%type,
                           v_birthday accountrequest.birthday%type,
                           v_workphone accountrequest.workphone%type,
                           v_homephone accountrequest.homephone%type,
                           v_address accountrequest.address%type,
                           v_state accountrequest.address%type,
                           v_zip accountrequest.zip%type,
                           v_email accountrequest.email%type );
    V_REQ R_REQ;
    CURSOR C_REQ IS SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTREQUEST_TEMP;
    
    BEGIN
     OPEN C_REQ;
     LOOP
      INSERT C_REQ INTO V_REQ;
      exit when c_req%notfound;
      dbms.output.put_line(V_REQ.BRANCH, V_REQ.ACCOUNT_TYPE, V_REQ.TITLE, V_REQ.FIRSTNAME, V_REQ.LASTNAME, V_REQ.BIRTHDAY, V_REQ.WORKPHONE,V_REQ.HOMEPHONE,V_REQ.ADDRESS,V_REQ.STATE,V_REQ.ZIP,V_REQ.EMAIL);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE C_REQ;
    END;
```

Comment: Why are you using PL/SQL and a loop instead of a mere INSERT in SQL? Is this for practice?

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error? Is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is for educational purposes, you don't need PL/SQL (especially not a loop). SQL can handle it:

```
insert into main_table (branch, account_type, title, firstname, ...)
select branch, account_type, title, firstname, ...
  from temp_table;
```

- ID will be auto-incremented (so you don't have to specify it in `INSERT`)
- column with default value will get it (so you don't have to specify it either)

---

If it has to be a loop, then

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select branch, account_type, title, firstname, ...
                from temp_table)
  loop
    insert into main_table (branch, account_type, title, firstname, ...)
      values (cur_r.branch, cur_r.account_type, cur_r.title, cur_r.firstname, ...);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is a cursor `FOR` loop which is simpler to use than explicitly declared cursor (and a cursor variable, opening the cursor, taking care about exiting the loop, closing the cursor) because Oracle does all that for you, only if you use cursor `FOR` loop. I suggest you do so.